# Randomizing not working c#

Tags: c#

so i have been trying to work on some randomizing of dice, but there seems to be a problem. So my question is basically what am i doing wrong? the code is below. on the design page, i have 2 picture boxes, each with 6 faces of a dice.
i have 2 labels showing what dice number you got. i have 2 more labels underneath the picture boxes that say win. i also have one label in the middle that says tie if it is a tie. Help would be appreciated!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Practice_randomizing
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random Rand = new Random();
        int Random = Rand.Next(6);

        int player1;
        player1 = 0;
        int player2;            
        player2 = 0;

        if
        (Random == 0)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.dice_11;
            label1.Text = "You got a 1!";
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        }

        else
        if
        (Random ==  1)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.dice_21;
            label1.Text = "You got a 2!";
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        if
        (Random == 2)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.dice_31;
            label1.Text = "You got a 3!";
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        if
        (Random == 3)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.dice_41;
            label1.Text = "You got a 4!";
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        if
        (Random == 4)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.dice_51;
            label1.Text = "You got a 5!";
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.dice_61;
            label1.Text = "You got a 6!";
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;


            {
                int dice2 = Rand.Next(6);
                if
                    (dice2 == 0)
                {
                    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.dice_11;
                    label5.Text = "You got a 1!";
                    pictureBox2.Visible = true;
                }

                else
                        if
                        (dice2 == 1)
                {
                    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.dice_21;
                    label5.Text = "You got a 2!";
                    pictureBox2.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                        if
                        (dice2 == 2)
                {
                    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.dice_31;
                    label5.Text = "You got a 3!";
                    pictureBox2.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                        if
                        (dice2 == 3)
                {
                    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.dice_41;
                    label5.Text = "You got a 4!";
                    pictureBox2.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                        if
                        (dice2 == 4)
                {
                    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.dice_51;
                    label5.Text = "You got a 5!";
                    pictureBox2.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.dice_61;
                    label5.Text = "You got a 6!";
                    pictureBox2.Visible = true;


                    if
                          (Random == 0 && dice2 == 0)
                        label4.Text = "Tie!";

                    if
                   (Random == 0 && dice2 == 0)
                        label4.Text = "Tie!";

                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 1 && dice2 == 1)
                        label4.Text = "Tie!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 2 && dice2 == 2)
                        label4.Text = "Tie!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 3 && dice2 == 3)
                        label4.Text = "Tie!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 4 && dice2 == 4)
                        label4.Text = "Tie!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 5 && dice2 == 5)
                        label4.Text = "Tie!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 1 && dice2 == 0)
                    {
                        label2.Text = "Win!";
                        player1++;
                        label4.Text = " " + player1;
                    }
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 1 && dice2 == 2)
                        label3.Text = "win!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 1 && dice2 == 3)
                        label3.Text = "win!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 1 && dice2 == 4)
                        label3.Text = "win!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 1 && dice2 == 5)
                    {  label2.Text = "win!";
                    player1++;
                    label6.Text = " " + player1;
                }
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 2 && dice2 == 0)
                        label2.Text = "Win!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 2 && dice2 == 1)
                        label2.Text = "win!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 2 && dice2 == 3)
                        label3.Text = "win!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 2 && dice2 == 4)
                        label2.Text = "win!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 2 && dice2 == 5)
                        label2.Text = "win!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 3 && dice2 == 0)
                        label2.Text = "win!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 3 && dice2 == 1)
                        label2.Text = "win!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 3 && dice2 == 2)
                        label2.Text = "win!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 3 && dice2 == 4)
                        label3.Text = "win!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 3 && dice2 == 5)
                        label3.Text = "win!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 4 && dice2 == 0)
                        label2.Text = "win!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 4 && dice2 == 1)
                        label2.Text = "win!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 4 && dice2 == 2)
                        label2.Text = "win!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 4 && dice2 == 3)
                        label2.Text = "win!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 4 && dice2 == 5)
                        label3.Text = "win!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 5 && dice2 == 0)
                        label2.Text = "win!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 5 && dice2 == 1)
                        label2.Text = "win!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 5 && dice2 == 2)
                        label2.Text = "win!";

                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 5 && dice2 == 3)
                        label2.Text = "win!";
                    else
                   if
                   (Random == 5 && dice2 == 4)
                        label2.Text = "win!";

                    label2.Text = " ";
                    label3.Text = " ";
                    label4.Text = " ";



















                }
            }
        }
    }



























}
```

}

Comment: Describe your problem, please.

Comment: Tip #1: stop copy-pasting. No sane person wants to review your cthuluan conditional statement.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't closed your chains of `if ... else` statements, so the code for picking the second dice is inside the code for when the first dice is a 6, and the code for checking a winner is inside the code for when the second dice is a 6.

Put a `}` to close the last `else` of those two chains of `if ... else` statements, so that the following code always runs.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem seems to be the IF... ELSE and ELSE IF. When you write the else if code you have given a line break and thus it becomes

```
else 
    if 
        (condition)
```

which up to my understanding is else condition in which there is another If. and thus your program seems to be buggy. please give a new line only if needed and try to follow the syntax of the language. Hope the code below will gonna help you

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Practice_randomizing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random Rand = new Random();
            int Random = Rand.Next(6);

            int player1;
            player1 = 0;
            int player2;
            player2 = 0;

            if
            (Random == 0)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.dice_11;
                label1.Text = "You got a 1!";
                pictureBox1.Visible = true;
            }

            else if(Random == 1)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.dice_21;
                label1.Text = "You got a 2!";
                pictureBox1.Visible = true;
            }
            else if(Random == 2)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.dice_31;
                label1.Text = "You got a 3!";
                pictureBox1.Visible = true;
            }
            else if(Random == 3)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.dice_41;
                label1.Text = "You got a 4!";
                pictureBox1.Visible = true;
            }
            else if(Random == 4)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.dice_51;
                label1.Text = "You got a 5!";
                pictureBox1.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.dice_61;
                label1.Text = "You got a 6!";
                pictureBox1.Visible = true;

                {
                    int dice2 = Rand.Next(6);
                    if(dice2 == 0)
                    {
                        pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.dice_11;
                        label5.Text = "You got a 1!";
                        pictureBox2.Visible = true;
                    }
                    else if(dice2 == 1)
                    {
                        pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.dice_21;
                        label5.Text = "You got a 2!";
                        pictureBox2.Visible = true;
                    }
                    else if(dice2 == 2)
                    {
                        pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.dice_31;
                        label5.Text = "You got a 3!";
                        pictureBox2.Visible = true;
                    }
                    else if(dice2 == 3)
                    {
                        pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.dice_41;
                        label5.Text = "You got a 4!";
                        pictureBox2.Visible = true;
                    }
                    else if(dice2 == 4)
                    {
                        pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.dice_51;
                        label5.Text = "You got a 5!";
                        pictureBox2.Visible = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.dice_61;
                        label5.Text = "You got a 6!";
                        pictureBox2.Visible = true;

                        if(Random == 0 && dice2 == 0)
                            label4.Text = "Tie!";
                        if(Random == 0 && dice2 == 0)
                            label4.Text = "Tie!";

                        else if(Random == 1 && dice2 == 1)
                            label4.Text = "Tie!";
                        else if(Random == 2 && dice2 == 2)
                            label4.Text = "Tie!";
                        else if(Random == 3 && dice2 == 3)
                            label4.Text = "Tie!";
                        else if(Random == 4 && dice2 == 4)
                            label4.Text = "Tie!";
                        else if(Random == 5 && dice2 == 5)
                            label4.Text = "Tie!";
                        else if(Random == 1 && dice2 == 0)
                        {
                            label2.Text = "Win!";
                            player1++;
                            label4.Text = " " + player1;
                        }
                        else if(Random == 1 && dice2 == 2)
                            label3.Text = "win!";
                        else if(Random == 1 && dice2 == 3)
                            label3.Text = "win!";
                        else if(Random == 1 && dice2 == 4)
                            label3.Text = "win!";
                        else if(Random == 1 && dice2 == 5)
                        {
                            label2.Text = "win!";
                            player1++;
                            label6.Text = " " + player1;
                        }
                        else if(Random == 2 && dice2 == 0)
                            label2.Text = "Win!";
                        else if(Random == 2 && dice2 == 1)
                            label2.Text = "win!";
                        else if(Random == 2 && dice2 == 3)
                            label3.Text = "win!";
                        else if(Random == 2 && dice2 == 4)
                            label2.Text = "win!";
                        else if(Random == 2 && dice2 == 5)
                            label2.Text = "win!";
                        else if(Random == 3 && dice2 == 0)
                            label2.Text = "win!";
                        else if(Random == 3 && dice2 == 1)
                            label2.Text = "win!";
                        else if(Random == 3 && dice2 == 2)
                            label2.Text = "win!";
                        else if(Random == 3 && dice2 == 4)
                            label3.Text = "win!";
                        else if(Random == 3 && dice2 == 5)
                            label3.Text = "win!";
                        else if(Random == 4 && dice2 == 0)
                            label2.Text = "win!";
                        else if(Random == 4 && dice2 == 1)
                            label2.Text = "win!";
                        else if(Random == 4 && dice2 == 2)
                            label2.Text = "win!";
                        else if(Random == 4 && dice2 == 3)
                            label2.Text = "win!";
                        else if(Random == 4 && dice2 == 5)
                            label3.Text = "win!";
                        else if(Random == 5 && dice2 == 0)
                            label2.Text = "win!";
                        else if(Random == 5 && dice2 == 1)
                            label2.Text = "win!";
                        else if(Random == 5 && dice2 == 2)
                            label2.Text = "win!";
                        else if(Random == 5 && dice2 == 3)
                            label2.Text = "win!";
                        else if(Random == 5 && dice2 == 4)
                            label2.Text = "win!";

                        label2.Text = " ";
                        label3.Text = " ";
                        label4.Text = " ";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no difference between having the `else` and `if` on separate lines or on the same line. There is no `elseif` in C#, an `else if` is always an `if` inside an `else`.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to move your instance of Random out to Class level so you use the **same** instance over with each Button click:

```
private Random Rand = new Random();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ... rest of your code ...
}
```

Comment: Well, in this case it's actually not needed, as the click gives plenty of time between each new Random instance, but it is a good practice to reuse the instance.